# java 9 module-info annotation access_flag ACC_MODULE is set error

Tags: java, annotations, java-9

I have the following annotation

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({PACKAGE, MODULE, TYPE})
public @interface Version {
    int major();
    int minor();
}
```

that i use in the *module-info.java* :

```
@Deprecated(since = "1.2", forRemoval = false)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Version(major = 1, minor = 2)
module com.jdojo.module.api.annotation {}
```

then inside the package `com.jdojo.module.api.annotation` i have another a call to the annotations of the module

```
public class AnnotationTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Module m = AnnotationTest.class.getModule();
        Annotation[] ann = m.getAnnotations();
    }
}
```

@ m.getAnnotations() i have the error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: module-info is not a class because access_flag ACC_MODULE is set` .

Comment: I tried to duplicate this but was unable to. Can you paste in the stack trace? Also the `java -version` output so that we can see why JDK 9 build this is.

Comment: Can be duplicated when running on classpath.